# Tools to refactor names of types, functions and variables?

Tags: d

```
struct Foo{
    Bar get(){
    }
}

auto f = Foo();
f.get();
```

For example you decide that `get` was a very poor choice for a name but you have already used it in many different files and manually changing ever occurrence is very annoying.

You also can't really make a global substitution because other types may also have a method called `get`.

Is there anything for D to help refactor names for types, functions, variables etc?

Comment: Maybe [Visual D](http://rainers.github.io/visuald/visuald/StartPage.html) can help.

Comment: If I remember correctly MonoDevelop with D language plugin can do some basic refactoring like this.

Comment: @sigod Probably should have said that I am on linux.

Comment: @Kozzi11 Also tried MonoD, renaming only seemed to work for local variables. Also I was hoping more for some standalone tools. I mean surely someone must have discovered some workflow for refactoring in D by now, even if it is not the cleanest.

Comment: @MaikKlein I try monod now and it works perfectly for methods and other things

Comment: @Kozzi11 You are right, I am not sure why it didn't work the last time I tried it. Sadly the vim mode is pretty horrible in Monodevelop, so I can't use it as my main dev tool but I guess I could just use it to refactor stuff.

Comment: I have to revise my last comment, it only works for the very basic stuff so far. It breaks for aliases or template arguments like `Array!Foo` and most other types that are templated. Not sure how useful it would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

1. Change the name in the definition
2. Recompile
3. Go to the first error line reported and replace old with new
4. Goto 2

That's semi-manual, but I find it to be pretty easy and it goes quickly because the compiler error message will bring you right to where you need to be, and most editors can read those error messages well enough to dump you on the correct line, then it is a simple matter of telling it to repeat the last replacement again. (In my vim setup with my hotkeys, I hit F4 for next error message, then dot for repeat last change until it is done. Even a function with a hundred uses can be changed reliably* in a couple minutes.)

You could probably write a script that handles 90% of cases automatically too by just looking for ": Error: " in the compiler's output, extracting the file/line number, and running a plain text replace there. If the word shows up only once and outside a string literal, you can automatically replace it, and if not, ask the user to handle the remaining 10% of cases manually.

But I think it is easy enough to do with my editor hotkeys that I've never bothered trying to script it.

- The one case this doesn't catch is if there's another function with the same name that might still compile. That should never happen if you do this change in isolation, because an ambiguous name wouldn't compile without it.

In that case, you could probably do a three-step compiler-assisted change:

1. Make sure your code compiles before. Then add `@disable` to the thing you want to rename.
2. Compile. Every place it complains about it being unusable for being disabled, do the find/replace.
3. Remove `@disable` and rename the definition. Recompile again to make sure there's nothing you missed like child classes (the compiler will then complain "method foo does not override any function" so they stand right out too.

So yeah, it isn't fully automated, but just changing it and having the compiler errors help find what's left is good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Some limited refactoring support can be found in major IDE plugins like Mono-D or VisualD. I remember that Brian Schott had plans to add similar functionality to his [dfix](https://github.com/hackerpilot/dfix) tool by adding dependency on [dsymbol](https://github.com/Hackerpilot/dsymbol) but it doesn't seem implemented yet.

Not, however, that all such options are indeed of a very limited robustness right now. This is because figuring out the fully qualified name of any given symbol is very complex task in D, one that requires full semantics analysis to be done 100% correctly. Think about local imports, templates, function overloading, mixins and how it all affects identifying the symbol.

In the long run it is quite certain that we need to wait before reference D compiler frontend becomes available as a library to implement such refactoring tool in clean and truly reliable way.

Answer (score 1):

A good *find all* feature can be better than a bad refactoring which, as mentioned previously, requires semantic.

Personally I have a *find all* feature in Coedit which displays the context of a match and works on all the project sources.

[image]

It's fast to process the results.